# Under Usage my Messages shows 1.1GB Used but I don't see any messages. How can I find and delete them?

Tags: iphone

Under Usage my Messages shows 1.1GB Used but I don't see any messages. How can I find them and delete all 1.1GB of the messages?

Comment: if your Messages app is totally empty & you still see high usage, then try... 1. reboot the phone. 2. sync the phone. 3. backup & restore the phone.

Answer (score 1):

I got this tip from http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-clear-message-imessage-cache-on-iphone-ipad/

You’ll need:

- iBackupbot (Download)
- Your iPhone/iPad
- PC/Mac running latest version of iTunes

Follow these steps:

- Backup your iPhone or iPad through iTunes. (Connect your iDevice to
  the PC/Mac, under the devices in iTunes, right click on your device
  and click on Backup Now; alternatively, you can also use the Back Up
  option from the Summary tab)
- Open iBackupbot
- From the sidepane, navigate to System Files > Mediadomain > Library >
  SMS > Attachments
- All the folders within Attachments are your Message cache containing
  all photos, video and media that you sent/received. Clear them out.
  At its best, delete all folders.
- Click on “Restore” so your iPhone is now restored to this backup.

Obviously, it doesn’t end here. If you have an iCloud backup already, you might have to flush that too. Go to Settings → iCloud → Storage & Backup and clear out any backup that exists. You can create a new backup.